# Exponential performance drop in XPath expression

Tags: xml, performance, xpath, lxml

Observations are in the context of Python 3 and [lxml](https://lxml.de/); however, with lxml building on [libxml2](http://www.xmlsoft.org/) I suspect that the observations may be related to the lxml or libxml implementation of XPath, not so much XPath itself.

Suppose a very large XML document with a fixed structure:

```
<root>
  <info> ... </info>  <!-- Handful of text-only children. -->
  <meta> ... </meta>  <!-- Often empty. -->
  <data>
    ...  <!-- Lots of nested elements of various depth. -->
  </data>
  <data> ... </data>
  ...
<root>
```

The document contains two elements, `<info>` and `<meta>` as its first and second child, and then any number of `<data>` elements. While the first two are either empty or very simple, the data elements may contain fairly complex content.

To get a sense for the document:

```
count(/root//*)
246076.0
count(/root//text())
263746.0
count(/root/*[1]//*)  <!-- <info> element. -->
8.0
count(/root/*[2]//*)  <!-- <meta> element. -->
0.0
```

When I started to traverse the data elements in the document, I noticed the following *exponential* performance degradations:

```
<!-- Select all elements. -->
/root//*
106.15 ms

<!-- Select data elements only. -->
/root/*[position() > 2]//*
187840.98 ms
/root/*[name() != 'meta' and name() != 'info']//*
205450.18 ms
```

Get the list of all children `/root/*` and slice that list in Python, then gather all of the data elements:

```py
list(e.xpath("//*") for e in xml.xpath("/root/*")[2:])
# 34455.04 ms
list(e.xpath("//*") for i, e in enumerate(xml.xpath("/root/*")) if i > 1)
# 34326.75 ms
list(e.xpath("//*") for i, e in enumerate(xml.getroot().iterchildren()) if i > 1)
# 34126.89 ms
```

Finally, if all I want is to traverse all descendents of all data elements, then remove the first two children

```
>>> root = xml.getroot()
>>> root[0]
<Element info at 0x10b8a9140>
>>> root[1]
<Element meta at 0x10b8a9280>
>>> root.remove(root[0])
>>> root.remove(root[1])
```

and select all elements

```
/root//*
107.16 ms
```

I’m puzzled by these severely different performance numbers. My guess is that lxml or libxml2 might maintain an index of all elements that’s queried within millisecs, whereas selecting data elements only causes an actual traversal of the entire document.

**Question:** How can I explain these different performance numbers?

**Addendum:** After fixing the above Python code as per [Daniel’s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63003983/exponential-performance-drop-in-xpath-expression#comment-111415713), performance of selecting all descendants of all data elements from the manual slice improves:

```py
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(e.xpath(".//*") for i, e in enumerate(xml.getroot().iterchildren()) if i > 1)))
# 134.74 ms, selects 244870 elements
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(e.xpath(".//*") for e in xml.xpath("/root/*") if e.tag not in ("meta", "info")))
# 131.43 ms
```

Comment: Shouldn't `e.xpath("//*")` be `e.xpath(".//*")` so the xpath is relative to the new context?

Comment: @DanielHaley, hmm I thought that `e` defines the context node which scopes the XPath selector but I was wrong. You’re correct, changing to a relative path takes `135.73 ms`. So… a “select everything” `//*` is _way_ faster than a conditional expression, independently of subtree context?

Comment: `e` is the context node, but you have to add the `.` (which means current context) otherwise your xpath is absolute from root. If `e` was the new root you wouldn't be able to do anything with the ancestors/parent. I don't know if `//*` is faster than a relative path or not. To find out you'd probably have to reduce it to only the xpaths and no other Python constructs (for loops, list comprehension, etc.).

Comment: @DanielHaley, I’ve added an _Addendum_ to my question. Still (and even more so now) I am puzzled & surprised that `/root/*[position() > 2]//*` is so very much slower than selecting all elements `/root//*` or the manual slice!

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking - the time taken for xpath is partially dependent on the complexity of the path. /root//* counts all elements without condition, so is simple and fast.
/root/*[position() > 2]//* has to assess the position of every element, so it takes longer
/root/*[name() != 'meta' and name() != 'info']//* has to check against the name of every element so it takes longer. 
Why is this surprising?

Comment: @Jens I don't know about the implementation of the libxml2, but I am working on another XPath engine. The problem may be due to the concatenation of the results from each "//*" per element. While /root/*[position() > 2] is quick, the engine evaluates //* on each element in the result sequence from /root/*[position() > 2] one element at a time. My guess is that each iteration results in a new sequence which is summed with the previous iteration rather than a more efficient concatenation of all sequences in one call. This likely causes excessive result array copying, exponential in cost.

Comment: @Bryn, both `/root/*[position() > 2]//*` and `/root/*[name() != 'meta' and name() != 'info']//*` need to check only the direct children of `root`, and not every element. But I guess that depends on _how_ evaluation happens: breadth-first (i.e. evaluate the path left-to-right), or in some other way. Similar to what @kaby76 points out.